# PHP system() gives different results than terminal, missing fonts

Tags: php, linux, terminal, ubuntu-14.04, cairo

**My issue**

I am using cairosvg on linux Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with PHP and apache. I am running it with the php function `system()`. This is the command I am running.

```
cairosvg -f pdf -o /var/www/dev/output.pdf /var/www/dev/input.svg
```

When I run this in terminal, I get the expected results, it generates the pdf file as expected. However when I run this in php using `system()`, it still generates the pdf file, but does not use the correct fonts.

**What I've tried**

The fonts are installed. The file permissions for both the folder and the fonts have been set to 777. Apache has been set as a co owner to the font folder and the font. File paths are absolute. `echo` on `system()` gives no errors. I have tried using equivalent alternatives to `system()` as well.

**1st Major UPDATE:** I've tried running this ImageMagick command to check the difference in available fonts. `convert -list font` On Terminal I see my installed fonts, but not on the `system()` call.

**2nd UPDATE** I ran `printenv` command in both terminal and `system()` and saw they had different values. I set HOME and USER environment variables using `proc_open()`, but I get the same results. Code is as follows.

```
$command = "cairosvg -f pdf -o /var/www/dev/output.pdf /var/www/dev/input.svg";
$descriptorspec = array();
$pipes = array();
$env = array(
    'HOME' => '/home/ntwdev',
    'USER' => 'ntwdev',
);
$resource = proc_open(
    $command,
    $descriptorspec,
    $pipes,
    $cwd = null,
    $env
);
```

**Why are fonts only coming through when I run the command in terminal and not in `system()`**

Comment: A few things you could check: 1) Does apache or whatever terminal user is used when using `system()` have access to the font folders? 2) The paths may be different when running it via PHP so it could not be finding the correct font files and substituting it to the default ones. 3) Is there any output if you `echo` the `system()` command like any errors at all?

Comment: @JamieBicknell Tried these, no luck, updated question.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. Are you asking why `cairosvg` cannot see your fonts when run via `system()` in PHP under Apache whereas ImageMagick (which is neither cairosvg, nor PHP, nor Apache) can see your fonts? Why do you think the two things are related?

Comment: @MarkSetchell No. Exact same command is run in terminal and `system()`, the first command `cairosvg -f pdf -o /var/www/dev/output.pdf /var/www/dev/input.svg`. The second command, `convert -list font` is only to check the differences in fonts available between terminal and `system()`. I will update question to clarify.

Comment: I'm feeling a bit dim today, and I still don't get it! Are you saying both `cairosvg` and `ImageMagick` work fine from the Terminal, but neither can see your font files when run under PHP+Apache?

Comment: @MarkSetchell exactly correct. Same commands, different results between terminal and `system()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to execute some command to re build the font cache before the create PDF command?

I can think of:

```
$ xset fb rehash
```

From the man page:

> The  rehash  argument  resets the font path to its current value, causing the server to reread the
>   font databases in the current font path.  This is generally only used when adding new fonts  to  a
>   font directory (after running mkfontdir to recreate the font database).

If you have fonts in special directories you could:

```
$ xset +fp /usr/share/fonts/misc
```

Comment: They work in Terminal, but appear to fail in `system()`. What do those commands mean and do?

Comment: Did you try `<?php system("xset +fp /usr/share/fonts/misc && xset fb rehash && cairosvg -f pdf -o /var/www/dev/output.pdf /var/www/dev/input.svg"); ?>`?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that cairosvg and/or the apache user of `www-data` could only access the fonts if it was in the `/usr/share/fonts` folder, regardless of file or user permissions.